# Mastodon api. How to get one status (toot)

Tags: javascript, bots, mastodon

I'm making my first bot for Mastodon with this library: [vanita5 mastodon api](https://github.com/vanita5/mastodon-api).

I'm trying to get a single toot (status) with:

```
M.get(`statuses/:108545593646026372`, {}).then(resp => console.log(resp.data))
```

But I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Mastodon: Params object is missing a required parameter for this request: 108545593646026372
```

What parameters should I pass to get function?

[This is the code in context](https://github.com/aitormendez/loro/blob/main/bot.js#L48-L50)

Answer (score 2):

The path should be "statuses/:id" and the status id should be supplied as a parameter. Like this:

`M.get("statuses/:id", { id: '108545593646026372' }).then(resp => console.log(resp.data))`

[Mastodon - statuses API methods - View a single status](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/statuses/#get)